# Is it possible to search for specific scopes with elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to perform text searches on documents based on the following scopes:

1. Whole document
2. Chapters
3. Paragraphs
4. Sentences

Is it possible to index a document so that you I can filter the scope of the query based on this requirement?

**Edit due to the answers**

I have now created the following index

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "folding": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [ "lowercase", "asciifolding" ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "books": {
      "properties": {
        "content": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "english": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "english"
            },
            "folded": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "folding"
            }
          }
        },
        "author": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "language": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "source": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "fileType": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "sections": {
      "_parent": { "type": "books" },
      "properties": {
        "content": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "english": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "english"
            },
            "folded": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "folding"
            }
          }
        },
        "paragraphs": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "paragraph": {
              "properties": {
                "page": { "type": "integer" },
                "number": { "type": "integer" },
                "html_tag": { "type": "string" },
                "content": { "type": "string" }

              }
            }
          }
        },
        "author": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "language": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "source": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "fileType": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "messages": {
      "properties": {
        "content": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "english": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "english"
            },
            "folded": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "folding"
            }
          }
        },
        "paragraphs": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "paragraph": {
              "properties": {
                "page": { "type": "integer" },
                "number": { "type": "integer" },
                "html_tag": { "type": "string" },
                "content": { "type": "string" }

              }
            }
          }
        },
        "author": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "language": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "source": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "fileType": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which gives me the following types: Books, Sections(parent Books) and Messages. Sections and Messages has the nested type Paragraphs and I have skipped the sentence level.

I can now perform searches on content on the book level, content on the section level. Which allows me to search for words between paragraphs. I can also search directly on the paragraph level which is helpful if I want to match two words in a paragraph.

Example: Let say  I have the following document

```
paragraph 1: It is a beautiful warm day.
paragraph 2: The cloud is clear.
```

I can now search for beautiful AND cloud on the content level and get back the document. I do however not get back the document if I search for beautiful AND cloud on the paragraph level using nested search, which is what I wanted.

The problems I see width this solution are:

1. I need to index the same paragraph 3 times. Once on the Paragraph level, once in the content Section level and once in the content Book level.
2. I do not understand what benefit I am getting from having parent/child relationship between Books and Sections. I haven't found any way of searching both at the same time using highlighting.
3. I need a separate Message type which is exactly the same as Section type without parent. Is there no way of having a children type without parents so that I can avoid an extra type?

Comment: maybe with custom analysers https://qbox.io/blog/introduction-to-elasticsearch-analyzers, one can create a custom analyser/tokeniser/ngram to group words into sentences and so on.., then the inverted index will have this structure and can be queried as such (although not a trivial task even for expert programmers in the field)

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/analysis-intro.html, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-analyzers.html

Comment: could you provide one sample document so that we can understand better?

Comment: Thank you Nikos M for your suggestions. They do however feel a bit complicated at the moment and I will look at them in the future when I have something working.

Comment: ChintanShah25: Does my updated question help or do you feel like I need to add more information?

Comment: This is getting quite verbose as i'd need to actually implement the mapping, index some content there and write different queries for running on different levels of hierarchy. My suggestion doesn't have child/parent relationships, just each sentence is stored as a nested doc and all data is stored only once. I think it is possible to construct "should" filters and use terms aggregation on for example nested doc's paragraph field and set min_doc_count larger than one, this way you find paragraphs which gets matches from different sentences.

Comment: Actually any level of hierarchy can be aggregated as "terms" by using a scripted field: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script, script could concatenate strings like book_id/chapter_id/paragraph_id, or these could be generated at indexing time so chapter_id wouldn't be an int but a string. It should perform a bit better.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve this you can index all sentences and along with the words of the sentence you include the information about the enclosing context, i.e. in which paragraph, chapter and book is the given sentence.

Then querying for terms will return you sentences and along with them the information about the chapter and book. With this information you know which sentence, paragraph, chapter or book is meant.

Then you simply use whatever scope you're interested in.

Example document to index:

```
{
    "book": <book-id>,
    "chapter": <chapter-id>,
    "paragraph": <paragraph-id>,
    "sentence": <sentence-id>,
    "sentence_text": "Here comes the text from a sentence in the indexed book"
}
```

**Additional answer after question clarification**

To achieve this you could use different document types stored in the same index. Then you can use one query which will return documents of possibly different types (paragraphs, books, etc). Afterwards by filtering the result type, you get what you want. Here is an example:

*Entire book:*

```
POST /books/book/1
{
    "text": "It is a beautiful warm day. The cloud is clear."
}
```

*1st paragraph:*

```
POST /books/para/1
{
    "text": "It is a beautiful warm day."
}
```

*2nd paragraph:*

```
POST /books/para/2
{
    "text": "The cloud is clear."
}
```

*Query to retrieve documents:*

```
POST /books/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "text": {
                "query": "beautiful cloud",
                "operator": "and"
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my question with my current solution which is similar to your suggestions. The only problem if I understand your solution is that I can't search for words between sentences since they are different documents. Is that correct? Can you please look at my current solution and give me suggestions on how I can improve it?

Comment: I am giving you the correct answer since it is very similar to my current solution. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

An other alternative is to have a single document / book but have many [nested documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) within, this way they can all share the same "book" context at the root level. It is up to you if you'd have one level of hierarchy (all sentences as nested documents) or more (capter => paragrap => sentence). A single level would keep queries simpler to write.

```
{
    "book": 123,
    "author": "Harry",
    "written": 1995,
    "sentences": [
        {
            "chapter": 1,
            "paragraph": 2,
            "sentence": 3,
            "text": "abc def"
        },
        {
            "chapter": 2,
            "paragraph": 3,
            "sentence": 4,
            "text": "ghi jkl"
        },
        { ... }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. My current solution is similar to yours. I have a parent book type and child section type. The section type have nested paragraph types. I have skipped the sentence level since I felt like it is going to be to much. Can you please look at the issues I have with this solution and help me with any suggestions?